# Netsuite - Validate Line Item Function to Check Duplicates

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I try to compare the current line item index with the line number and see if they are the same with a new sales order. If the two numbers are the same then skip the validation otherwise check if they are the same item. However, it doesn't always return the line number which I wonder why.

Here are the two variables that I want to compare:

```
var linenum= nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','line');
var currentIndex = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemIndex('item');
```

linenum does return a number sometimes but most of the time it returns null; when that happened the comparison doesn't work. When I logged the variables, index always shows up correct. Is there any other parameter I can use to grab information from creating sales order page?

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var linenum= nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','line');

linenum will only have a value if the line was saved previously. If linenum is null it means the user is trying to add a new Line item and not edit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That means the order items have to be saved first before edit...? I tried to edit the items in a previously saved order and it also returns null though...? What other variables are good to be used to do line item validation if 'line' is not available...?

Comment: I get value with 

     var linenum= nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item','line');
on clicking of ok button of the current line if its a new line.